# Convert UIView to UIImage to save as binary data in Core Data

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimage

I am trying to save a UIView as a UIImage to save in the Core Data database. My code is causing a compile error at `self.canVasView.image` stating:

> Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'image'.

I think part of this code works in Swift 4 but it is not working in Swift 5.

```
var canVasView = UIView()

@objc func hhh() {
    let photo = self.canVasView.image
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo!)

    if cdHandler.saveObject(pic:  data!){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a specific subclass of `UIView`.

Try using:

```
var canVasView = UIImageView()
```

Of course, you need to actually set the `.image` property to some `UIImage` in order for the call to `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to actually work.